# Getting hWnd from current process

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I tried to get hWnd from current process using **GetCurrentProcess** function to display path to each process. But I got an error in this line: `User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, pid);`
How to convert it to the desired type?

> The method GetWindowThreadProcessId(WinDef.HWND, IntByReference) in the type User32 is not applicable for the arguments (WinNT.HANDLE, IntByReference)

There is my code:

```
try {
    while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
        kernel32.GetCurrentProcess();
        HANDLE hWnd = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess();
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, pid);

        HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010,
                false, pid.getValue());
        psapi.GetModuleFileNameExA(process, null, path, 1024);

        System.out.println(Native.toString(path));
    }
} finally {
    kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
}
```

**UPD:**
The problem was solved in this way:

```
try {
    while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {

        HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010,
                false, processEntry.th32ProcessID.intValue());
        if (process != null) {
            int len = psapi.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, null, path,
                    1024);
            if (len > 0) {
                System.out.println(new String(path, 0, len));
            } else {
                System.out.println("GetModuleFileNameW failed");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(kernel32.GetLastError());
        }
        System.out.println(process != null ? Native.toString(path) : "error");
    }
} finally {
    kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: GetCurrentProcess returns a PID, not a HWND. And there is no point calling GetCurrentProcess in a while loop, the API will always return the same value: the PID of **current** process. Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to display list of paths of running processes.

Comment: May you suggest how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** get a list of Process Identifiers (PID) using the Win32 API [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629.aspx) or the Win32 APIs [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx) / [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834.aspx) / [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836.aspx) / [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx)

**B)** with each PID, use the win32 API [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to obtain a HANDLE for the process (request for PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION as dwDesiredAccess). With that handle, use the Win32 API [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217.aspx) (and do not forget to close the HANDLE with CloseHandle)

Hope this helps (as that's not JAVA code, sorry for that)